# Treat Symbolic Links as Folders in Nautilus FTP

Tags: ftp, nautilus, filezilla, pure-ftpd

I have a Pure-FTPd server running with the `virtualchroot`-enabled binary. When I connect to the server with FileZilla, FileZilla shows a link overlay for symbolic links that point to folders, but I can navigate to those folders successfully.

However, when I connect to the server with GNOME Files (Nautilus), GNOME Files shows a generic document icon for the link and gives the error `This link cannot be used because its target "../relative/path/to/target" doesn't exist.` when I try to navigate to it.

It seems that FileZilla is letting the server handle the link while GNOME Files is trying to interpret the link itself. Can I change GNOME Files to treat the link as a normal directory?